# Sum of data by month, while being filterable

Tags: filter, excel-2013

I am trying to sum the values by month while using filter in excel 2013. I have used two different method but did not get the desired result. Following are both methods.
1.     =SUBTOTAL(109,H8:H65535)
2.     {=SUM(IF(MONTH(A8:A65535)=2,H8:H65535,0))}

First method calculates the sum dynamically but not by month. Second method calculate the sum by month but not dynamically.

I need to calculate the sum dynamically (need to update the values with filter) by month.

So suggest a function for the desired result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `=2` in your `{=SUM(IF(MONTH(A8:A65535)=2,H8:H65535,0))}` to '=$G$2` . where you can change the value of G2 at anytime to get the new answer (for other month)